# query that returns distinct count of each value in each column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to query a table structured like so

```
A B C D E
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 1 1 2
2 2 2 1 3
4 4 5 5 5
```

to see the column_name, distinct_value_in_column, count_of_distinct_value like so

```
A 1 1
A 2 2
A 4 2
B 1 1
B 2 2
B 4 1
C 1 2
C 2 1
C 5 1
D 1 3
D 5 1
E 1 1
E 2 1
E 3 1
E 5 1
```

Ultimately I'd like to sort by count descending, but it's getting to this structure that puzzles me. Can this be done in SQL generally? I'm using a postgresql instance if that has any impact.

In pseudo code I'm envisioning

```
select column_names, distinct a, b, c, d, e, count (`distinct a, b, c, d, e) as ct
from table
group by column_names
order by ct desc
```

Comment: Also see normalisation

Comment: Yeah, what Strawberry said. If your tables are in proper normal form, you shouldn't really be having to write queries like this in the first place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT col, val, count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT unnest(array['A','B','C','D','E']) AS col,
         unnest(array[A,B,C,D,E]) AS val
  FROM mytable) AS t
GROUP BY col, val
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5662d/7)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Stack the data first using `UNION`.

```
select
    col,
    val,
    count(*)
from
    (
        select
            'A' as col,
            a as val
        from
            table
        union all select
            'B' as col,
            b as val
        from
            table
        union all select
            'C' as col,
            c as val
        from
            table
        union all select
            'D' as col,
            d as val
        from
            table
        union all select
            'E' as col,
            e as val
        from
            table
    )
group by
    col,
    val
order by
    count(*) desc;
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was thinking. Is there any way to generalize that such that I can apply this logic to a number of different tables without knowing their column names, or will I have to manually input each column name?

Also, is there a way I could apply a `where` clause to each select statement at once, or would that also have to be added to each line?

Comment: Sure. You could look into dynamic sql. I've never done it in Postgres (only M$ SQL Server), but it looks like Postgres supports some flavor of it. If you don't mind me asking, can you give any more detail about what's in the columns? It's very likely that you could save a lot of trouble by storing this data in a 'long' rather than 'wide' format, but maybe you have your reasons.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into dynamic in postgres. Typically they're codes, so column a might be a department code, b might be a subcategory code, other qualifying text indicators.